# Putting multiple POST API in a single Resource class in Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, rest, http, post

I am going to implement a POST API in an existing resource class `StudentResource`, which contains already a POST REST API in order to create a `Student`.

The new POST API is basically for validating a `Student` entity, of the following form:

```
POST /api/student/validate

 Request Body:  
  {
     student_id : <>,
     validation_type : <>
  }
```

Now, I am not able to understand, should I create a new resource class: `StudentValidationResource` to put this new validate REST API or should I put this in the existing `StudentResource`.

**EDIT:**

The intent of the question is actually whether should I put more than one POST API in a single resource class.

Could anyone please help here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you think about using validator?  With javax @valid  directly for your controller params / body?
You juste have to set the constraints in the object if the post receive an object, or directly in the controller like

```java
@PostMapping("someurl") 
public void myController(@valid @requestParams @size(min=2, Max=10) String aString) {}
```

I have a doubt if valid come before or after the requestParams.

Comment: thanks for your respose. Actually intent of my question is whether should I put more than a single POST API in a single resource.

Regarding validator, I am implementing my validation logic as a workflow, where @valid annotation will not work.